# How to find the maximum and minimum for specific columns in each row

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
Class   Budget  Total   Rank                                    
A        120    1926    58     5    9      2       10      3                
B        120    3146    52     6    15     1       6       7    8   9       
C        120    2358    51     2    1      4                        
D        120    3252    57     5    16     0.5     9       7    6   33  4   6
```

I would like to get the maximum and minimum value for each row starting from the column after the Rank (i.e., those columns that don't have titles).

What I want is to include the max and min within the data frame like:

```
Class   Budget  Total   Rank   max    min                                   
A        120    1926    58     10     2    5    9      2       10      3                
B        120    3146    52     15     1    6    15     1       6       7    8   9       
C        120    2358    51     4      1    2    1      4                        
D        120    3252    57     33     0.5  5    16     0.5     9       7    6   33  4   6
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It's not really possible to not have column names in a data frame. (They can be `""`, but that's still a name.) Similarly, you can't really have data with nothing there—it can be `NA` or `""` or something, but it still exists. For anyone to work with this dataset, you'll need to call `dput` on it and edit your question with the results—otherwise there's no way for anyone to read it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
df[, "Max"] <- apply(df[, 5:length(df)], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
df[, "Min"] <- apply(df[, 5:length(df)], 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)
```